# products not displaying

Tags: magento

I have been working on creating a e-commerce store using Magento and I think I'm having a bit of a blonde moment, as none of my products are displaying.

I have created a category and a basic simple product, which is in stock, has stock, enabled and assigned to the category. When I navigate to the category on the front end, the product is not displaying. The category is set to display 'products only'.

I have re-indexed, cleared cache, but cannot think of the reason why this is happening.

I can access the product via it's url, but cannot see it in the category page.

Am I missing something? I haven't touched any of the category/product templates, so this is a bit odd.

Thanks

Comment: What about 'Visible in' attribute?

Comment: That's set to 'Catalog, Search'

Comment: Also check that your have added your store to your 'website' if you have more than one listed Catalog -> Manage Products -> "Select Product" if there is a "Website" tab on the left select it and check your website click save

Comment: I have added all the products to the default store/website and still no products in the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to mass re-enable product. This should help.

Also check out by FTP magento-install/var/log/system.log and exception.log files.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Then you are looking wrong site i guess :) If you have 2 different root categories check that you current store has root category this where you added your products.